# How do i implemente a 301 redirect for secondary domains on a Bitnami Apache web server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, bitnami

While searching for documentation on how to run 301 redirect for secondary domains on a Bitnami Apache web server on AWS, i came across a Bitnami guide to redirecting custom domains to the Apache server ([here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/redirect-custom-domains)/). However, i don't know if this method would also work for the secondary domains.

Assistance with 301 Redirect Setup